# ES6+React, Error:React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

Learning ReactJS with ES6. Trying to implement React-Bootstrap components. I am also using the react router. I am trying to implement the Navbar component.

It will just be a nabber with the brand and a search box. I aim to expand and use the search box component a lot more so I have put it in its own separate component below.

LocationSearchBox.js

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import Form, {FormGroup, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function LocationSearchBox(props) {
    return (
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" />
            <Button bsStyle="success" type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </FormGroup>
    )
}
```

The navber will be on all pages so I have put it in the topmost route and its component is the Main.js file shown below along with routes.js to manage client side routes.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Navbar, NavbarHeader, NavbarBrand, NavbarCollapse} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {default as Search} from './LocationSearchBox'

export default class Main extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Navbar>
                <NavbarHeader>
                    <NavbarBrand>
                        <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
                    </NavbarBrand>
                </NavbarHeader>
                <NavbarCollapse>
                    <Search/>
                </NavbarCollapse>
            </Navbar>

        )
    }

}
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactRouter, {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Main from '../components/Main';

export var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Main} />

    </Router>
);
```

Index.js is below and is the entry file to use in Webpack/babel

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {routes} from './config/routes';

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So when i run web pack-dev-server, go to localhost:8080 as the default port the main route should be hitting. I believe it does but I get errors, namely 3 of the same kind.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Main`.
```

I believe it might be due to the way I am importing the Navbar components in Main.js, such as NavbarHeader, NavbarCollapse etc but that is a guess. I would really appreciate any help in solving this issue, thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you tried replacing <a></a> with Link from react-router?

Comment: Is there more to the warning or some stack trace that's available in the console? I think the best way to go about debugging this is removing all the elements except for one and adding each one and seeing which one is breaking it.

Comment: @KumarM yea I did what you said, checking each component one by one. I figured out the problem was NavbarCollapse, instead of the JSX syntax being <NavbarCollapse>.... it has to be <Navbar.Collapse>. I don't know why because the header and brand components are not the same.

Comment: if it's not the solution to this cryptic message might be the diffenrence between `import {foo} from 'foo'` vs. `import foo from 'foo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **using the `Button` component without importing** it:

```
<Button bsStyle="success" type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

Import it correctly and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: It was two issues, the JSX syntax 'NavbarCollapse' was one issue, and I posted the solution in a common on the OP. However this fixed my second issue. Thank you